# start an activity from a thread class in android?

Tags: android, handler

I am extending a thread class and from that class I want to start an activity. How to do this?

This is my Extended thread class code : http://pastebin.com/phkVUH5v

and this is my Activity that i want to move to : http://pastebin.com/UKBAfwWB

I know that i need to do something with Handler but i read everywhere and i do not understand what.

There is anybody that can help me please ? :)

Comment: post the code here itself

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can give a Handler in params and send a message to the UI thread via this handler from your extended thread.

Take a look a the documentation about sendMessage and handleMessage.